# Show that $xRy$ if and only if $x, y$ are in the same part of the partition defines an equivalence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Let $S$ be a set and $\{X_i\}$ be a partition of $S$. Show that $xRy$ if and only if
$x, y$ are in the same part of the partition, defines an equivalence relation.
What are the equivalence classes of this relation?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am uncertain how to prove this iff statement

Comment: What have you tried as of yet? Can you guess what an equivalence relation on the partition might be?

Comment: I know the equivalence classes of an equivalence relation form a partition. But I am not sure how can a equivalence relation on a partition？

Comment: Let's try to guess - for the partition formed by an equivalence relation, what are the equivalence classes?

Comment: You are not asked to prove any iff thing.  The iff statement is part of the definition of an relation that you are to show is an equivalence relation.

Comment: check out this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052501/consider-p-a-partition-of-set-a-given-relation-r-on-a-and-xry-if-and-only-if-x?rq=1